I deposited some Solana from the exchange
I deposited some Solana from the exchange to my phantom wallet. I entered the Volt address correctly, the transaction was completed, but the amount of Solana was not added to my Volt. I had set the network to sol, I'm sure I entered everything correctly. And what's worse is that the hash of my transaction that I enter is not recognized. Can anyone guide me?
